# Eclipse Code Formatter Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, formatter

Can some one suggest me a plugin to format HTML and JAVA code with proper indents etc ? Is there any built in option there in Eclipse ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse does have built in Java formatting:

`Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`

For HTML, you might try something like [HTML Tidy](http://eclipsetidy.sourceforge.net/). The [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) project also includes formatting.

Answer (score 9):

Use Source -> Format or CTRL+SHIFT+F

Comment: STRG+SHIFT+F only works if you haven't changed that binding, of course.

Answer (score 4):

It's a combination of all the answers above, which suits me-

1. Go to `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter` and set all the options you want by creating your own profile or using a default one. Personally I find the line-wrap limited to 80 a little too low. I set it to 200.
2. Save the 'custom' preferences by giving it a new profile name (export it for future restoration)
3. Select the code in your editor - then hit `CTRL+SHIFT+F`. That should format your code.

Worked wonders for me everytime.

Answer (score 3):

Java code formatting is built in. Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter. There's a built in profile set up and you can make your own.

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jalopy/

Note that Jalopy has its settings under Window> Jalopy Preferences.

*(This menu option appears only when all editor tabs are closed)*

Eclipse doesn't have *proper* built-in code formatting. You might want to open your project in Idea IntelliJ or Netbeans and use their formatting to do a thorough job on it.

Comment: +1 for `Eclipse doesn't have proper built-in code formatting`. Currently, Eclipse formats my ternary conditional statements and there's no way to turn it off...

Comment: jalopy is pretty much dead - it doesnt work in recent versions of eclipse, the configuration menu is completely missing and the formatting fails with no error message.

Comment: Hight time somebody wrote a plugin!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prettier Formatter Plugin in Eclipse to format your code better than inbuild eclipse formatter
Click this link: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/prettier-formatter