# Eclipse badly formats a method with a return statement

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-formatter

if my method contains a single statement...

```
if (some-condition) {
  return someObject.methodOne().methodTwo().methodThree().methodFour();
}
```

Eclipse formatting "collapses" it to...

```
if (some-condition) {return someObject.methodOne().methodTwo().methodThree().methodFour();}
```

However, if my method contains more than one statement...

```
 if (some-condition) {
        int a = 42;
return something;
}
```

Eclipse formatting cleans it up and keeps in on multiple lines...

```
 if (some-condition) {
  int a = 42;
  return something;
}
```

If my method has only a single return statement I *still* want it to occupy multiple lines.  I *never* want it to be "collapsed" to a single line.

How can I configure Eclipse formatting for the behavior I want? I've playing with the settings for quite a while without success.

Thanks!

Comment: Your method *can't* just contain `if (some-condition) {
  return someObject.methodOne().methodTwo().methodThree().methodFour();
}`, you'd have a way to get to the end without returning. Did you just mean control statement or branch? And what language is this for?

Comment: @nitind Sorry, I forgot to state that this is Java.
<br/>
Yes, a method _can_ contain just a return statement. This a simplified example that presents the *specific* problem.  BTW the Eclipse formatter exhibits the same behavior if the method contains only a "throw" statement -- another common pattern.
<br/>
Back to the question of the Eclipse formatter... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

First: Go to `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter` and set all the options you want by creating your own profile or using a default one.

Second: Save the 'custom' preferences by giving it a new profile name (export it for future restoration)

Then you could use the short cut and try it. Also see this interesting answers here [Eclipse Code Formatter Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473905/eclipse-code-formatter-plugin)

Comment: Thanks, but I've been spending a lot of time tweaking those settings.  Can't find anything that addresses this specific case.  If you know of some *specific* settings, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Found the setting in the Formatter (Neon) that controls this behavior:

- Control Statement -> 'if else' -> Keep ‘return’ or ‘throw’ clause on one line